# textContent within evenlistener returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue, I can't manage to find what's wrong.
I'm trying to update the price of a p element i selected, and using an input eventlistener I do the maths. Without the last line, the newPrice variable contains the right number. 
Whenever i try to adapt the text content it returns NaN instead?

```
          <div class="subts_wrapper">
          <div class="subt__wrapper">
            <p class="cart__item__subtitle sub__margin">Subt.</p>
            <p class="cart__item__price"><?php echo $itemTotal?></p>
          </div>

            <div class="subt__amount">
            <label class="cart__item__subtitle" for="aantal">Aantal</label>
              <input class="cart__item__amount" id="aantal" type="number" name="quantity[<?php echo $item['product']['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']?>">
              <button type="submit" id="update-cart" class="btn has-js" name="action" value="update">Update Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="remove__icon" type="submit" name="remove" value="<?php echo $item['product']['id'];?>">
        </div>
```

```
{
  document.querySelector('.has-js').style.display = 'none';
  const $amountField = document.querySelector('.cart__item__amount');
  const $itemPrice = document.querySelector('.cart__item__price');
  const init = () => {
    $amountField.addEventListener('input', updateCart);

  };

  const updateCart = e => {
    console.log(e.target.valueAsNumber);
    const $itemAmount = parseFloat(e.target.valueAsNumber);
    const $decimalText = $itemPrice.textContent;
    const decimalTextToNumber = $decimalText.replace(',', '.');
    const decimal = parseFloat(decimalTextToNumber);
    const newPrice = decimal * $itemAmount;
    console.log(newPrice);

    $itemPrice.textContent = newPrice;
  };

  init();
}
```

Comment: can you share the relevant HTML  (of the various fields you're selecting and listening to) and also an example of input data and the expected result. It's not immediately obvious (to me anyway) what the exact issue is. It'd be useful to a have enough code and data to actually run it.

Comment: P.S.To be clear, are you saying that when you do `console.log(newPrice);`, you see the correct price value in the console, but when you do `$itemPrice.textContent = newPrice;` you see `NaN` in the element instead?

Comment: Yes indeed, when i add the line: $itemPrice.textContent = newPrice; suddenly everything is NaN. When the line isn't there, all const contents are as I want them to be. I will add the HTML in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all instances of `valueAsNumber` with just `value` and your calculation should work.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of using the `value` property:

```js
const $amountField = document.querySelector('.cart__item__amount');
const $itemPrice = document.querySelector('.cart__item__price');
const init = () => {
  $amountField.addEventListener('input', updateCart);

};

const updateCart = e => {
  const $itemAmount = parseFloat(e.target.value);
  const $decimalText = $itemPrice.textContent;
  const decimalTextToNumber = $decimalText.replace(',', '.');
  const decimal = parseFloat(decimalTextToNumber);
  const newPrice = decimal * $itemAmount;
  console.log(newPrice);

  $itemPrice.textContent = newPrice;
};

init();
```

```html
<input class="cart__item__amount"/>
<p class="cart__item__price">578,67</p>
```

**N.B.** But you will have to write additional logic if you want to re-calculate when someone uses the backspace to remove everything and type something else.

---

To prevent the `NaN` output, just check if the current value of your input exists or not and if it does, run your calculation, else do nothing like this:

```js
const $amountField = document.querySelector('.cart__item__amount');
const $itemPrice = document.querySelector('.cart__item__price');
const init = () => {
  $amountField.addEventListener('input', updateCart);

};

const updateCart = e => {
  if (e.target.value) {
    const $itemAmount = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    const $decimalText = $itemPrice.textContent;
    const decimalTextToNumber = $decimalText.replace(',', '.');
    const decimal = parseFloat(decimalTextToNumber);
    const newPrice = decimal * $itemAmount;
    $itemPrice.textContent = newPrice;
  }
};

init();
```

```html
<input class="cart__item__amount"/>
<p class="cart__item__price">578,67</p>
```

Comment: In the eventListener properties list there is one called ValueAsNumber. It's identical to value, I thought I would give it a try. The calculations work with this value, but it's after the last line ($itemPrice.textContent = newPrice;)  Newprice returns NaN.

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys I can't seem to replicate this NaN output in the above snippet other than when I backspace everything and type a new number.

Comment: Ah, it is indeed due to the backspacing. My field had a value in it when refreshed, so I automaticallyt started backspacing to test. Could you recommend eventlisteners to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to add another function. Just add an if statement inside your `updateCart()` function that checks if the input has a value or not and if it doesn't, default it to 0.

Comment: Hold on. I'll edit my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: Actually, defaulting it to 0 wouldn't be the correct way to do it. Just ad an if statement that checks if the input has a value or not and if it doesn't, don't run the calculation. That way, the last amount inside your `p` tag will remain as it is and will continue re-calculating when the input is not empty again. Check the second Code Snippet that I've added.

Comment: Thanks, there is another problem though; When I backspace and/or type new numbers in the input, the newPrice keeps adding up. It changes, but not according to the simple calculation.

Comment: Yes, the above approach, makes sure the p value doesn't change to NaN when you backspace everything and continues the calculation when you type a number.

Comment: Could you guide me to a solution? I'm genuinely stuck, my JavaScript knowledge isn't very impressive;

Comment: What exactly would you want the p tag value to change to when you backspace everything?

Comment: I just want it to calculate the subtotal constantly, so amount * price. So everytime there is a value in the input, it takes that value and multiplies it with the price of the element. I don't want it to keep stacking the multiplications.

Comment: I figured out a solution, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out for one item, but I don't know how to implement it if there are multiple $amountField / $amountPrice in the document. I tried doing a queryselectAll, and then doing a foreach on the input fields, but I don't know how I am supposed to change the p tag that belongs to the right input field.

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys Sounds like you need to use the closest() method for that but it's out of the scope of this current question. You can open a new question and I or someone else can show you how to do it there.